# Manipulating freshly uploaded file causes IOException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

My Asp.net MVC app requires a file upload. In the course of the upload I'd like to manipulate the freshly uploaded file.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection) {
    Block block = userrep.GetBlock(id);
    foreach (string tag in Request.Files) {
        var file = Request.Files[tag] as HttpPostedFileBase;

        if (file.ContentLength == 0)
            continue;

        string tempfile = Path.GetTempFileName()
        file.SaveAs(tempfile);
        // This doesn't seem to make any difference!!
        // file.InputStream.Close();

        if (FileIsSmallEnough(file)) {
            // Will throw an exception!!
            File.Move(tempfile, permanentfile);
        } else {
            GenerateResizedFile(tempfile, permanentfile);
            // Will throw an exception!!
            File.Delete(tempfile);
        }

        block.Image = permanentfile;
    }
    userrep.Save();
```

The problem with this snippet is that any attempt to manipulate the initially uploaded file generates an IOException("The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.") Of course I can bypass the problem by copying rather than moving uploaded file but I still can't delete it once I have a better alternative.

Any advice?
Duffy

Comment: maybe you have to flush() the stream first?

Comment: Couple of questions: is HttpPostedFileBase your own implementation under the hood? (I noticed it is abstract in the docs). What is the code for FileIsSmallEnough?  Usually, you get this process error when some of your own code above the point of problem has not closed/disposed itself and is designed to hold onto file handles.  The File static helper class contains a couple of methods that return objects that hold files, for example, if you don't dispose these it's pot luck if the GC gets it cleared before you need to use it.

Comment: @Jocke: I tried flush() as well. No difference.

Comment: @Adam: HttpPostedFileBase is provided by the Asp.Net magic. I didn't overwrite it although I also can't tell who did implement it. Either way this seems to be the standard way of file uploads for MVC

Comment: @Adam: FileIsSmallEnough generates an Image object (using (Image img = Image.FromFile(tempfilename)) {...}) from the just uploaded file, then checks the size of the image. It doesn't contain any reference to the file object. As far as I am concerned I am done with file at this point and would happily release it if I knew how.

Comment: @duffy I've answered the question, but have just noticed that you are already using the using statement to manage the Image.  In that case, this is not the source of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your comments, you load an `Image` from file.  The MSDN documentation states that the file remains locked until the image is disposed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx

To dispose your image, you can either call the `Dispose` method on the instance, or use the preferred mechanism of the `using` statement:

```
private bool FileIsSmallEnough()
{
    using (Image i = Image.FromFile())
    {

    }
}
```

This should solve the problem.